# jQuery ajax failing after the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I set up a link that queries the Instagram API and displays images. I want it so when I click on the link again it refreshes and gets me newer images (or multiple links). But it always fails after the first click.

```
   <div class="keywords">
   <p id="olympics"><a href="#">#olympics</a></p>
   <p id="london"><a href="#">#london</a></p>
   </div>
```

And this is my JS:

```
  $(".keywords").live('click',function()

  {        
      $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      cache: false,
      url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/olympics/media/recent?client_id=XXXXXXXXX&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      success: function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              $(".pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +
              "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
                                      }
                              }                

      })
  }
  );
```

Comment: can you print the contents of `data` at both the first and second times ?

Comment: Use `.on()` or `'.delegate()` instead of `'.live()` it's bad practice and will be deprecated anyway.

Comment: Define 'fails'. Can you set up a Fiddle?

Comment: The first time it retrieves the data just fine. The second time nope. Here:
http://ramitaibah.com/olympics/#

Comment: Or tell us any errors you see in you console or XHR log?

Comment: No XHR errors in console @RobinMaben

Comment: you are using 'append', so it won't act as a refresh, it will just add the images again. Maybe you should use `$('.pics').empty()` before the loop

Comment: @Rami I got a missing `)` before `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: and also `event.preventDefault();` is called but no `event` parameter is specified in the click event callback function like so `$(".keywords").live('click',function(event)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refresh the pics list on a new click you might want to empty the `.pics` div before appending the new images.

```
$(".pics").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $(".pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +
"'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
}
```

since as it is now pics are appended to the list not replaced.

**EDIT**

Sorry `$(".pics").empty();` should be before the for loop not inside it.

Comment: Just edited the answer as I put the `empty()` in the wrong place :D

Comment: This works just fine. Thank very much. I am just not getting my head around why I should empty the div prior the loop? Shouldn't it at least append?

Comment: Because each time you retrieve items with your ajax call you add them at the end of the pics list. Before adding `empty()` the call was working also, but the images were appended (remove the `empty()` and see more images being added at the end on each click if you scroll down). To replace (refresh) them you need to empty the `.pics` container first and start adding the newly retrieved images.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're getting a javascript error when processing the first results as your for loop runs 10 times no matter what results are returned. This could then be stopping the second request from running.

Try changing the contents of the success callback to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    $(".pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
}
```

I changed the 10 to data.data.length, this way it will only loop over the number of results returned.

If you want to only display a max of 10 do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length && i < 10; i++) {
    $(".pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/h6NgP/

You just had a bracket error ;) minor syntax thing. works the first time in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I see problem with this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

You've hard coded 10. Are you sure you are geeting "FRESH" list of images every time?
Or it might be the case that the new images are appended to the JSON and you are not seeing this just because you are iterating over it only 10 times.